# Mesh Replacement

Tags: mesh

[image: Small plant]

Is there a way to replace a mesh with another one?. Like planes instead of leaves, so i can apply a masked material instead of a high poly mesh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In blender, objects have an associated mesh, ad you can change it, like this:

[image]

if you have many objects using the hires mesh, you could create a script to mass change meshes...

another way, maybe is to link data from one sample mesh, like this:

[image]

here select all target objects, and leave the "sample" on as last.

Comment: Thank you! but what did you do to see that frame

"cube
sphere"

Comment: sorry my screen capture lost the cursor... look in the right panel, where you can change the dropdown (small triangle icon )

Comment: added another possible way...