# Replace animated object (mesh plus material) with new one

Tags: animation, mesh, materials, objects

I have animated an object which also has a material on it. Now I want to replace this object with a more detailed version without having to set all the animation keyframes (location + rotation) again. Is there a way to do this? thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to replace an object?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65128/is-there-any-way-to-replace-an-object)  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/100029/mesh-replacement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select your object, shift select the object you want to copy the mesh from, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> *(Make Links) > Object Data*.

Or in the *Object Data* panel, in the top dropdown menu, select the mesh you want to replace with:

[image]